# Sort a list of strings and numbers in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to sort a list of strings. Each string contains numbers and letters and they are separated by space. I want to sort the list based on the numbers.

Example code:

```
list=["x 10","y 20"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may sort with the help of a lambda:

```py
list = ["x 10", "y 20", "z 15"]
list_sorted = sorted(list, key=lambda x: int(x.split()[1]))
print(list_sorted)  # ['x 10', 'z 15', 'y 20']
```

In the snippet above, the lambda expression splits each list element by space, and then casts the second element to an integer.  It is this value which is then used to sort the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
l=["x 10","y 20","z 15"]

n=len(l)

for i in range(n-1):

    for j in range(n-i-1):

        if int(l[j].split()[1])>int(l[j+1].split()[1]):
            l[j],l[j+1]=l[j+1],l[j]

print(f"sorted{l}")
```